# just returning non type parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I just learned *compile-time array* declaration via template, with the *non-type* parameter. so in this approach, we pass constant and array with size gets declared.
like

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<int size_of_array>
class arr 
{
public:
    int  arr[size_of_array];

    int size_of() { return size_of_array;   }
};

int main() 
{
    arr<4> arr1;
    cout << arr1.size_of();

    return 0;
}
```

Can we do something like variable value assigning at run time like if we remove `arr[]` from there.
like

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<int size_of_array>
class arr 
{
public:
    int  size_of_array;
    int size_of() { return size_of_array;   }
};

int main() 
{
    arr<4> arr1;
    cout << arr1.size_of();

    return 0;
}
```

Can we do that? or why not? Then maybe there is some thing about an array and a variable declaration which i don't know. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not clear, you mean you want to read a value for size at runtime?

Comment: yes, a variable like an array.

Comment: sir, can we do assigning value to a variable like we do for an array size

Comment: template parameters should be known at compile time.

Comment: Sir I am passing value like I did with array.

Comment: The `<4>` part can only contain a compile time constant. You can't do `arr<my_runtime_variable>` for example. *(if that's what you are asking...)*

Comment: Yes, sort-of, but probably the compile-time size would be a default size, or a maximum size, or something other than just the size. If you allow the size to vary at run-time, that size can't always be the same as the fixed size you specified at compile time. Of course you can also save the compile-time-specified size in a run-time variable that you then never change, so the compile-time and run-time size are always equal - there are even some cases where that can be useful (e.g. you need a run-time variable because you need to pass something a run-time pointer to that variable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely! You can expose the template parameters by writing a function to pass them through.

Your attempt only failed because:

- you tried to re-use the template argument name for a data member name, and
- you never actually assigned a value to the data member.

There's really no need for an additional data member here anyway, as the template argument is accessible throughout the class definition.

So, for a non-type template parameter like yours, just:

```
template <int size_of_array>
class arr 
{
public:
    static int size_of() { return size_of_array; }
};
```

Now `arr<42>::size_of()` is 42!

*(I've made it `static`, not because you need to, but because in this example it makes sense; you could alternatively make it a non-`static` but `const` member function.)*

And for a type:

```
template <typename T>
class arr 
{
public:
    using array_size_t = T;
};
```

Now `arr<T>::array_size_t` is the type `T`!

Comment: "I've made it both static and const" --> `static` member can't be `const`. I think you mean `constexpr` at the beginning. (BTW, I'd prefer `std::integral_constant` if I want to store a non-type argument inside the body)

Comment: @liliscent Haha good point. I put in `const` then thought "oooh should be `static` too" 

Comment: @liliscent I'll leave `constexpr` out of it for simplicity's sake but for production you're probably right